# Magento product with many custom options, need to update the prices with unique values for each product

Tags: magento-1.9, product, price, custom-options, csv

I have simple products with 1,815 custom options which are tartans, and I need to update the price with unique values for each product. Would I be able to achieve this using a CSV import or do I need to do it programatically using a script in the root folder?
If it is, **CSV file>>system>>import/export>>import**, what columns are required and do I need to include all of the information or only the information I need to update?

Apologise if this question seems either simplistic but I'm new to Magento and this is the last issue I have before finishing the configuration or my products.

Thanks you for any advice you may have.